# Azure ARM Template for Action Group: The template function 'listCallbackURL' is not expected at this location

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-deployment

I'm trying to deploy this ARM Template for an action group, with a logicAppReceiver attatched:
`

```
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "actionGroupName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "actionGroupShortName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "platformTag": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "stageTag": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "emailReceivers": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "logicAppName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "azureAppPushReceivers": {
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "logicAppReceivers": [
      {
        "name": "Logic App Action",
        "resourceId": "[if(empty(parameters('logicAppName')), '', resourceId('Microsoft.Logic/workflows',parameters('logicAppName')))]",
        "callbackUrl": "[if(empty(parameters('logicAppName')), '', listCallbackURL(concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Logic/workflows/', parameters('logicAppName')), '/triggers/manual'), '2016-10-01').value)]",
        "useCommonAlertSchema": "true"
      }
    ]
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2018-09-01",
      "name": "[parameters('actionGroupName')]",
      "location": "Global",
      "tags": {
        "platform": "[parameters('platformTag')]",
        "stage": "[parameters('stageTag')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "groupShortName": "[parameters('actionGroupShortName')]",
        "enabled": true,
        "emailReceivers": "[parameters('emailReceivers')]",
        "azureAppPushReceivers": "[parameters('azureAppPushReceivers')]",
        "logicAppReceivers": "[if(empty(parameters('logicAppName')), json('null'), variables('logicAppReceivers'))]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "actionGroupId": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups',parameters('actionGroupName'))]"
    }
  }
}
```

`
Where the parameter "logicAppName" can be excluded as a parameter, but getting the error: The template function 'listCallbackURL' is not expected at this location.
Can someone tell me my mistake.

I initially had:
`

```
"properties": {
        "groupShortName": "[parameters('actionGroupShortName')]",
        "enabled": true,
        "emailReceivers": "[parameters('emailReceivers')]",
        "azureAppPushReceivers": "[parameters('azureAppPushReceivers')]",
        "logicAppReceivers": [
          {
            "name": "Logic App Action",
            "resourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Logic/workflows',parameters('logicAppName'))]",
            "callbackUrl": "[listCallbackURL(concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Logic/workflows/', parameters('logicAppName')), '/triggers/manual'), '2016-10-01').value]",
            "useCommonAlertSchema": "true"
          }
        ]
      }
```

`
Which worked when including the logicAppName, but not when excluding it, and the current one works when excluding it, but not when including it.

Comment: Hi JakeLRL,

AFAIK the template function 'listCallbackURL' is not expected in variables section. As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#implementations) Azure document, the template function 'listCallbackURL' can be used in Microsoft.Logic/workflows or Microsoft.Logic/workflows/triggers or Microsoft.Logic/workflows/versions/triggers or Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts resource types.

Comment: Thanks! I've ended up using the listCallbackURL, as part of the output of the Logic App deployment and then using that variable in this file, and that has now worked.